# How to know how much data uploaded to web server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How to calculate how much data is uploaded to web server.

For the Image and string value, uploading into the web service. Want to calculate how much data its has been uploaded.

So i can put into `UIProgressView`

Comment: OT: you should accept more of your questions

Comment: I did not understand about accept more of questions?

Comment: View all your previous questions and accept the most accurate answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) On iOS < 5.0 implement following method in your delegate:

> Sent as the body (message data) of a request is transmitted (such as in an http POST request). (Available in iOS 3.0 through iOS 4.3.)

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
```

2) In iOS >= 5.0

> No documentation available

```
[NSURLConnectionDataDelegate connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:]
```